# MKMapKit issue Xcode 7 Released

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios9

Issue I am facing is my application freezes where a map is displayed on a view. No errors or crash are generated by Xcode just the application freezes . Both on simulator and real device. I am identified that issue persist because of the MKMapview since i remove it from my subview app functions fine.

Can some one please help me identify the root cause to this problem.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MKMapView *mapView;
@synthesize mapView;


self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotationPoint];
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.mapView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
self.mapView.showsUserLocation=YES;
self.mapView.scrollEnabled=YES;
 self.mapView.zoomEnabled=YES;
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:fromAddress animated:NO];

[self.mapView   setCenterCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(annotationCoord.latitude, annotationCoord.longitude) animated:NO];
 [self.mapView regionThatFits:region];
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this issue is that , adding the map view directly to view as a subview was creating a issue . so  I added a Table view as a subview of view and added map view as a background View of the tableview . worked